# Calculation not working

Tags: apex, trigger, case

I've got a trigger I'm working on and it's not calculating right. I am trying to count the number of Open System cases (indicated in the Send to: field). The calculation is not working. It doesn't seem to count over one and if I edit a case that's Not a System Sales case, it takes the count back down.

```
trigger OpenCasesSystemSales on Case (after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {
  List<Case> caseList = (trigger.isDelete)? trigger.old : trigger.new;
  set<Id> contactIdSet = new set<Id>();
  for(Case cs: caseList ){
     contactIdSet .add(cs.ContactId);
  }
if(contactIdSet.size() > 0){
    List<Contact> lstContact = [select id, Open_System_Sales_Cases__c, (select id, Send_To__c, status, Is_Closed__c from Cases)
    from Contact where id IN: contactIdSet ];
       if(lstContact.size() > 0){ 
          for(Contact con: lstContact)
          { 
             con.Open_System_Sales_Cases__c = con.Cases.size();
             Integer openCases = 0;
             for(Case cs : caseList){
                 if(cs.Is_Closed__c == false && cs.Send_To__c =='System Sales' )
                   openCases++;
             }
             con.Open_System_Sales_Cases__c = openCases;
          }
          update lstContact;
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please consider using the free and open source [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries). It is much easier than hand-rolling rollup triggers.

Comment: I have no budget and I am out of free roll ups.

Comment: DLRS is free and has no limit on rollups. It sounds like you may be using Rollup Helper, which is a "freemium" product.

Comment: I'll give it a look. I will say, I'm a bit bummed as I'm on my pathway to learning how to code, and I'd still like to learn how to do these kinds of things as they're often building blocks for the harder stuff.

Comment: Fundamental issue is only considering the cases passed to the trigger and doing an absolute setting of the count instead of performing an update based on delta change.

Comment: I was using another Q&A as a reference point (https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000kzU9QAI) as it said it was successful, so I modified it, but clearly it was flawed. So how would I modify?

Comment: pro tips: line`if(lstContact.size() > 0){` can be removed - when collections are empty, the loop does nothing; your SELECT statement is querying all Cases in the database

Answer (score 1):

So far, I don't see exactly how to produce the behavior you're describing. There's definitely a couple of issues here, but I can't reason out the straight line to the specific problem you articulate. If you have other automation running on this object, that's something to take into account.

I'd streamline the logic like this:

```
List<Contact> lstContact = [
   SELECT Id, 
          (SELECT Id, Send_To__c, status, Is_Closed__c 
           FROM Cases
           WHERE Is_Closed__c = false AND Send_To__c = 'System Sales')
   FROM Contact
   WHERE Id IN :contactIdSet 
];
for (Contact con : lstContact) { 
    con.Open_System_Sales_Cases__c = con.Cases.size();
}
update lstContact;
```

You can let the SOQL query do some of the work for you and make the update straightforward.

Another approach would be to do away with the direct SOQL query and use an aggregate query instead, which could look something like this:

```
Map<Id, AggregateResult> agrs = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
   SELECT ContactId Id, count() ct
   FROM Case
   WHERE ContactId IN :contactIdSet
         AND Is_Closed__c = false 
         AND Send_To__c = 'System Sales'
   GROUP BY ContactId
]);
List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();

// Since Aggregate Queries won't give us data on Contacts with 0
// Cases, iterate over the Contact Ids and source their count (or 0)
// from the Map
for (Id contactId : contactIdSet) {
    Integer count = (agrs.containsKey(contactId) ? agrs.get(contactId).get('ct') ? 0);
     contactList.add(new Contact(Id = contactId, Open_System_Sales_Cases__c = count));
}
update contactList;
```